# What's the difference between get_collection and get_collection_ref?

Tags: tensorflow, collections

I have checked the documentations of both methods but they look the same, except that get_collection can take an additional scope parameter.

```python
In [11]: aaa = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
In [12]: aaaa = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
In [13]: aaa == aaaa
Out[13]: True
In [14]: aaa is aaaa
Out[14]: False
```

What's the difference between the two and when to use which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this difference:

```
In [24]: w = tf.Variable([1,2,3], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS], dtype=tf.float32)
In [25]: params = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)
In [26]: params
Out[26]: [<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
In [27]: del params[:]
In [28]: tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)
Out[28]: []
In [29]: w = tf.Variable([1,2,3], collections=[tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS], dtype=tf.float32)
In [30]: params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)
In [31]: params
Out[31]: [<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
In [32]: del params[:]
In [33]: tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS)
Out[33]: [<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

So get_collection only returns the value of the collection, but get_collection_ref returns the **reference** of the collection then I can delete the collection by delete the returned variable it refers to.

And the scope parameter in the get_collection is for filtering variables by the scope name. But get_collection_ref don't offer such a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the **scope** argument in **tf.get_collection**, those two methods return the same collection in the computational graph.

**get_collection**, without **scope** fetches every value in the collection without applying any filter operation.

When the **scope** parameter is specified, every element of the collection is filtered by the scope.

Consider the following sample code, which returns the same as your sample code (here I used **tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES** instead for the demo purposes).

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo1"):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [1])
with tf.variable_scope("foo2"):
    v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [1])

aaa = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
aaaa = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)

print(aaa == aaaa) #True
print(aaa is aaaa) #False
```

Since there is no scope specified, **aaa** and **aaaa** objects referred to by the variables are equal.

However, If you run the following sample code with  the **scope** specified,

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo1"):
    v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [1])
with tf.variable_scope("foo2"):
    v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [1])

aaa = tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
aaaa = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,'foo1')

print(aaa == aaaa) # False
print(aaa is aaaa) # False
```

since the **scope** is specified, **aaa** and **aaaa** objects referred to by the variables are not equal.

Moreover, in both cases, **aaa** and **aaaa** are not pointing to the same object. Therefore, **aaa is aaaa** is **False** in both cases ([Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the difference you mentioned is not the essential one.. It relates to the scope difference only.